$USER on ubuntu SSSD with AD
We've got some Ubuntu boxes setup to use SSSD and Active Directory.
I've noticed that there's some inconsistencies in how the username is shown.
For example, for user xxxx:

$HOME is /home/xxxx
whoami is xxxx
$USER is xxx@company.domain.com

That crazy-looking $USER in particular causes lots of problems.  For example if you want to add yourself to a group:
sudo usermod -aG foo $USER

it won't work, because the user is actually xxx and not xxx@company.domain.com.  I've seen other examples of scripts falling down because the $USER isn't actually the user.
Where does $USER come from?  Can it be set to match whoami?

I also came to realize in my ldap+sssd setup for GNU/Linux, that if I merely needed all my users to have access to local devices in a Debian-like world, like being in groups cdrom,floppy,audio,video,plugdev, etc., then I needed to make those groups in ldap. Then when I add a system to the kerberos+ldap domain, I run a script to convert all these local groups to the ldap gids. Then I can just add my usergroup "public" to all these groups.

According to Unix.SE#answer-76356, the answer is login(1).
You might be able to split the output of this:
$ getent passwd "${USER}" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
bgstack15

But this entire thing sounds like a misconfiguration of sssd. You might want to adjust full_name_format in sssd.conf:
[sssd]
full_name_format = %1$s

Be advised that this might make things complicated if you have multiple domains to support with sssd.
